# Parsing list object file paths for file name

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, list

I am trying to automate a naming process that takes the file name from a list of file paths to name other folders, geodatabases, zipfiles, etc.

The problem I'm running into is that, I assume, I am trying to run string functions on list object and I can't figure out how to get the script to do what I need it to do.

For example, I have the file path C:\TEMP\Durham.shp. I want to name a geodatabase, folder, and zipfile "Durham". Instead I get a folder and geodatabase named "C".

Can someone take a look at my script and tel me what I'm doing wrong?

The following script is that last incarnation of several attempts.

```
import arcpy, os
import zipfile
from arcpy import env
from os.path import basename

BASELAYERS = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
CLIPLAYERS = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
OUTFOLDERMASTER = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
FILETYPES = ["*.shp", "*.dbf", "*.shx", "*.prj", "*.sbn", "*.sbx", "*.xml"]

env.workspace = OUTFOLDERMASTER
for LAYERS in CLIPLAYERS:
    LAYERSSTR = ''.join(LAYERS)
    BASENAME = LAYERSSTR.split("\\")[-1]
    FOLDER = os.path.join(OUTFOLDERMASTER, BASENAME)
    os.makedirs(FOLDER)
    PGDBNAME = "NCFlood_Effective_" + BASENAME + "_PGDB.mdb"
    arcpy.CreatePersonalGDB_management(FOLDER, PGDBNAME, "9.3")
    PGDB = os.path.join(FOLDER,PGDBNAME)
    for FILES in BASELAYERS:
        FEATURENAMESTR = ''.join(FILES)
        FEATURENAME = os.path.basename(FEATURENAMESTR)
        SHAPEFILENAME = FEATURENAME + ".shp"
        SHAPEFILE = os.path.join(FOLDER, SHAPEFILENAME)
        arcpy.Clip_analysis(FILES, LAYERS, FEATURENAME)
        arcpy.Clip_analysis(FILES, LAYERS, SHAPEFILE)
    ZIPFILELIST = []        
    for TYPE in FILETYPES:
        ZIPFILELIST.extend(glob.glob(FOLDER))
    ZIPFILENAME = os.path.join(FOLDER, "NCFlood_Effective_" + FOLDERNAME + "_SHP.zip")
    ARCHIVE = zipfile.ZipFile(ZIPFILENAME, "w")
    for ZIP in ZIPFILELIST:
        ARCHIVE.write(ZIP, os.path.basename(ZIP), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    ARCHIVE.close()
```

I have also tried

```
    BASENAME = os.path.basename(LAYERS)
    FOLDERNAME = os.path.splitext(BASENAME)[0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that in its current state `CLIPLAYERS` is a string and not a list.  This means that when you loop through it using `for LAYERS in CLIPLAYERS` it is going to give you one character at a time starting with `C`.

You can avoid this by adding `CLIPLAYERS = CLIPLAYERS.split(";")` before you loop through `CLIPLAYERS`.  This will create a list from a semicolon delimited string of layers.

Comment: @NCFMP - Don't forget to mark as answered, please.